# Setting the scrollbar position of Listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting the scrollbar position of a ListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159506/setting-the-scrollbar-position-of-a-listbox)

How can I set WPF listbox scroll bar position to the last item added?

Comment: Did you tried anything so far?

Comment: You can do it in code behind. Just like in this questions:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159506/setting-the-scrollbar-position-of-a-listbox

Comment: Yup. I tried others suggested way but it end with something wrong.

Comment: Maybe you should share what "end with something wrong" means so someone might be able to help you out.

Comment: What I mean for something wrong is nothing happened.. I tried those suggestions like Mr. @AdamBilinski provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply use the [ScrollIntoView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.scrollintoview.aspx) method:

```
object item = ...
listBox.Items.Add(item);
listBox.ScrollIntoView(item);
```

Answer (score 1):

In WPF you have to use `ScrollIntoView`.
I added this example:

```
int i = 0;
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{   
   listBox1.Items.Add("Item nr. " + i.ToString());
   listBox1.ScrollIntoView("Item nr. " + i.ToString());
   i++;
}
```

In Windows Forms you have this:

```
int visibleItems = myListBox.ClientSize.Height / myListBox.ItemHeight;
myListBox.TopIndex = Math.Max(myListBox.Items.Count - visibleItems + 1, 0);
```

Comment: I guess this is for windows forms right?

Comment: Yes, I think it works in Windows Forms.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a MVVM-aligned way using the ideas explained in [this post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28959/Introduction-to-Attached-Behaviors-in-WPF) - just map to a ListViewItem instead of a TreeViewItem (and instead of IsSelected being a trigger, you can set it to the new item being added).